# Rearranging linear system with complex conjugate matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I have three complex matrices $X$, $A$ and $B$. $A$ and $B$ are diagonal matrices, while $X$ is a full non-symmetric matrix.

I have an equation

$$ Y = XAX^T + \bar{X}B\bar{X}^T $$

where the overbar indicates complex conjugate.

I know the value of $C=(A+B)$. How can I express $Y$ in terms of $C$?

In other words, I'm trying to obtain something in the form

$$ Y = ? (A+B) ? $$

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hopeless. E.g. when $B=-A$, a product of the form $?(A+B)?$ is always zero, but $XAX^T+\bar{X}B\bar{X}^T=XAX^T-\bar{X}A\bar{X}^T$ can be easily nonzero.